# Convert 43435.010567129626 to a timestamp in r

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to convert `43435.010567129626` to `1/12/2018  00:15:13` in R.

I've tried 4 different ways, but none of them work.

```
parse_date_time(raw$Date, orders = c('dmy_HMS', 'mdy_HMS',"ymd_HMS"))
anytime(raw$Date)
strptime(raw$Date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
as.POSIXlt(raw$Date,format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This gives the day: `as.Date(x, origin = "1899-12-30") #Excel`.

Comment: I have tried in many ways and the time always gives `"00:15:13"`. Are you sure the posted time is right?

Comment: @RuiBarradas, yes, you are right, should be 00:15:13. Thanks for your help. as.Date(as.numeric(raw$Date), origin = "1899-12-30") gives me a date.  Still in search for a time through.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `as.POSIXct` with excel origin date.

```
as.POSIXct(43435.010567129626 * 86400, origin = '1899-12-30 00:00:00',tz = 'UTC')
#[1] "2018-12-01 00:15:12 UTC"
```